# How can I add ordering for ManyToMany field?

Tags: python, django

I have two models: `CustomUser` and `AgreementReglament`
At this moment relation between the models looks like this:

```
class AgreementReglament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32) # just name of the reglament
    approvers = models.ManyToManyField( # set of users to approve
        'CustomUser',
        related_name='agreement_reglaments'
    )
```

How can I set order of approvers (e.g. CustomUser1 should be the first in particular AgreementReglament1, CustomUser2 should be second and so on, but in AgreementReglament2 CustomUser2 can be the first)

**UPDATE**: ordering is based on the POST request data
Example of post request to create AgreementReglament:

```
{
        "name": "Reglament1",
        "approvers": [
             {
                  "approver_name": "Alex",
                  "approver_order": 1,
             },
             {
                  "approver_name": "Bob",
                  "approver_order": 2,
             }
        ]
    }
```

**UPDATE2**

```
class AgreementReglament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32) # name of the reglament
    approvers = models.ManyToManyField( # set of users to approve
        'CustomUser',
        related_name='agreement_reglaments',
        through='Approval'
    )


class Approval(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agreement = models.ForeignKey(
        AgreementReglament,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the approver order value will be entered as a field , then I would create a model lets say For example `Approvals` and it will have a `FK field for User` and a `FK field for Agreement` , and a third field for the `approver_order`. And leave the Agreement Model to have only name field.
But , If you mean to sort based on a condition , the question needs more details to be clarified as (what the ordering is based on ? What is the field you’re ordering exactly ?)

**UPDATE:**
After seeing your update what I understood is that you get this ordering from the POST request data and for the example you provided, you definitely need a field to store the order for each User.
I suggest going with the same answer, create a model in the middle and link both models with that Model using the `through` attribute and that might look like this:

```py
class Approval(models.Modal):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agreement = models.ForeignKey(AgreementReglament, ...)
    order = models.#whatever you want this char or int
```

and in one of the other models (doesn't really matter) they should be like this:

```py
class AgreementReglament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32) # just name of the reglament
    approvers = models.ManyToManyField( # set of users to approve
        'CustomUser',
        related_name='agreement_reglaments', through='Approval'
    )
```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Please, see UPDATE with answer on your question

Comment: I updated the answer. See if it solves your problem and please,  don’t forget to accept it as an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I added this code and received error:

ValueError: Cannot alter field admin_panel_app.AgreementReglament.approvers into admin_panel_app.AgreementReglament.approvers - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)

Comment: please, look at update 2